# Django: "cannot import name import_string" while using "rest_framework_docs"

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-1.6

I installed `drfdocs` by following the steps as mentioned [here](http://drfdocs.com/installation/). But I am getting `cannot import name import_string`.

Below is the stacktrace:

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name import_string
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name import_string
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework_docs/api_docs.py in <module>, line 4
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

I am using `Django 1.6.5` and `django-rest-framework-docs==0.1.7`

Below is the list of `pip packages` installed on my system:

```
moin@moin-pc:~/workspace/my_project$ pip freeze
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
boto==2.42.0
coreapi==2.0.0
dateutils==0.6.6
Django==1.6.5
django-cors-headers==1.1.0
django-countries==4.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.5
django-rest-framework-docs==0.1.7
django-rest-swagger==2.0.5
django-storages==1.5.1
django-tastypie==0.13.3
django-tastypie-swagger==0.1.4
djangorestframework==2.3.13
drfdocs==0.0.11
itypes==1.1.0
jsonpickle==0.9.3
mysqlclient==1.3.7
openapi-codec==1.0.0
Pillow==3.3.1
psycopg2==2.6.2
pygeocoder==1.2.5
python-dateutil==2.5.3
python-mimeparse==1.5.2
pytz==2016.6.1
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.11.1
simplejson==3.8.2
six==1.10.0
sqlparse==0.2.1
ua-parser==0.7.1
unity-lens-photos==1.0
uritemplate==3.0.0
user-agents==1.0.1
```

I am sure it is due to any conflict between package version. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to the conflict in the version of `drfdocs` with `django-rest-framework`. Downgrading my version from `drfdocs==0.0.11` to `drfdocs==0.0.6` fixed the issue.